# Levenshtein can't look for Russian words

Tags: mysql, levenshtein-distance

I have a script that searches the database for words using the Levenshtein. 
Everything is fine when I searching for English words, but when I searching for words in Russian, MySQL console gives out an error:

```
[22007][1366] (conn=31079) Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA1\xD0\xBA\xD0\xBE...' for column ``.``.`s1` at row 1
```

All my tables have CHARACTER SET utf8mb4.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE levenshtein(text_ru, 'testtest') BETWEEN 0 AND 1
```

My table "messages" column "text_ru":

```
================
=Твое имя?     =
================
=Твоя фамилия? =
================
...
```

Comment: If you don't get help here, then I suggest possibly posting to the [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) site, where you might get more help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another Levenshtein script, and it all worked out
https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/